# Помещение адреса с адресной строки в переменную

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Можно ли как-то адрес сайта, введённый в адресную строку, поместить в переменную?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Адрес ни надо никуда помещать, он уже хранится в суперглобальном массиве $_SERVER:

```
 $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

**Вывод текущей страницы:**

```
  echo "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

**Вывод полного адреса страницы с параметрами GET (если они были указаны):**

```
  echo "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```